# CSRF token not set in Django with Python Request

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-requests

I'm trying to send a POST request to a Django view from an ordinary Python script using Python-Request. The django view is **not** `@login_required`, so the only thing i need to send, other than my JSON data, is a CSRF token, here is what i tried:

```
token = session.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myview/view')
data = json.dumps({'test': 'value'})
session.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myview/myview',
             data={
                 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token,
                 'data': data})
```

The django view should just receive the Request and print it to my console:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('data')
        print(json.loads(data))
        print('received.')

    response = HttpResponse(get_token(request))
    return response
```

The problem with my current code is that my console will throw a `log: WARNING - Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)`. I cannot use `@csrf_exempt`, since i need this to be as safe as possible. Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why might a user encounter a CSRF validation failure after logging in?

For security reasons, CSRF tokens are rotated each time a user logs in. Any page

with a form generated before a login will have an old, invalid CSRF token and need to be reloaded. This might happen if a user uses the back button after a login or if they log in a different browser tab.

This also goes for cookies. After you log in, django will send a new csrf cookie to the client. This will be stored in client.cookies and replaces the old one. The django server does not keep any record of the old token, so that's why you get the "CSRF token missing or incorrect." response.

You can access the new token from request.cookies['csrftoken'] as before.

```
import requests

LOGIN_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/myview/view'
request = requests.session()
request.get(LOGIN_URL)
# Retrieve the CSRF token first
csrftoken = request.cookies['csrftoken']
r1 = request.post(LOGIN_URL, headers={'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
                          allow_redirects=False))
new_csrftoken = r1.cookies['csrftoken']
data = json.dumps({'test': 'value'})
payload = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': new_csrftoken,'data':data }
```

In fact, you can just use the client cookie directly. This would have avoided this bug in the first place. Requests keeps track of cookies for you when you use requests.session().

```
try :
    r2 = request.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myview/myview', data=payload, headers={'X-CSRFToken': r1.cookies['crsftoken']})
except :
    print('error expected')
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer! In this case, where is login_data defined?

Comment: ohhhh sorry i forget the login data !!! 
csrftoken = request.cookies['csrftoken']
login_data = dict(username='xxxx', password='xxxx', csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken)

Comment: Ok! One problem is that, as i said in the question, the url is not login_required, i do not need the user to log in!

Comment: Ok. I tried without login data but i got Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.):

Comment: Yes, i'm getting this: raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='csrftoken', domain=None, path=None"

Comment: i will try something just give me a time , try to put r2 in try block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205457/discussion-between-khaled-hadjali-and-jack022).

Comment: @Jack022 did you manage to have access to CSRF cookie using this?

Comment: Yes! The code in this accepted answer worked for me!